Mule4: Get job state bulk api v2 operator not able to find the job ID from salesforce
I am using Mulesoft to do a bulk query from salesforce object.
In the below code I am trying to extract the jobId from the output of "Create query job bulk api v2" operator. The job ID is passed as variable to the "Get job state bulk api v2" operator. However it gives the error. I am using it in "until successful" loop before pulling the result from the job.
"Invalid status code: 404, response body: [{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist"}]"

I can see the job created and completed in salesforce UI.

Not sure what I am missing and why it gives NOT_FOUND error. Please guide me.
Mule flow is as follows:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core" xmlns:batch="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch"
    xmlns:salesforce="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/salesforce"
    xmlns:bigquery="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/bigquery" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/bigquery http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/bigquery/current/mule-bigquery.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/salesforce http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/salesforce/current/mule-salesforce.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch/current/mule-batch.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd">
    <flow name="opportunitylineitem-queryjob" doc:id="c1c8ee87-db15-4d3e-a772-c9144cd30a5a">
        <http:listener doc:name="opportunityQuery job create" doc:id="f6480050-3a6f-417d-977b-b168bf84ead8" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/opportunity_queryjob" />
        <salesforce:create-query-job-bulk-api-v2 doc:name="Create opportunity query job bulk api v 2" doc:id="647f065e-45ef-481d-b8f1-b79eab2c80e3" config-ref="Salesforce_connection_configuration" operation="QUERY_ALL" query="select AccountId, Adjustment_Type__c, Agency_Dealer_Group__c, Agency_ID__c, Agency_Type__c, Agent__c, Agent_Email__c, Agent_Email_Address__c, Agent_First_Name__c, XML_Sent__c from opportunity" target="opportunitylineitem_job_output">
            <reconnect />
        </salesforce:create-query-job-bulk-api-v2>
        <until-successful maxRetries="5" doc:name="Until Successful" doc:id="e2efe92d-c6d7-42b6-a1f0-f477e9425fba">
            <salesforce:get-job-state-bulk-api-v2 doc:name="Get job state bulk api v 2" doc:id="ab38d0ae-0cb4-4a86-a953-796437b77d6e" config-ref="Salesforce_connection_configuration" id="#[vars.opportunitylineitem_job_output.id]" target="job_status" />
            <choice doc:name="Choice" doc:id="29dca2b6-5e04-4244-8773-f35aafb11702">
                <when expression="#[vars.job_status == 'JobComplete']">
                    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Job status" doc:id="73bce4f3-f46b-493b-8ae0-46dd623905a9" message='#["Job created with job_id : " ++ vars.opportunitylineitem_job_output.id]' />
                </when>
                <when expression="#[vars.job_status == 'InProgress']">
                    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="1680da7e-01ba-403a-a510-eac00adcccd7" message='#["Job is still getting created : " ++ vars.opportunitylineitem_job_output.id]' />
                </when>
                <when expression="#[vars.job_status == 'Failed']">
                    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="42c52005-f55b-4e4a-882b-6c4412a6d3ca" message='#["Job could not be created : " ++ vars.opportunitylineitem_job_output.id]' />
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <raise-error doc:name="Raise error" doc:id="5b776c51-1b03-430b-a0c4-99266974f6bb" type="ANY:TIMEOUT" />
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
        </until-successful>
        <salesforce:get-query-job-results-bulk-api-v2 doc:name="Get query job results bulk api v 2" doc:id="46c918b3-3b78-467d-ae40-6f772f1c1c8d" config-ref="Salesforce_connection_configuration" id="#[vars.opportunitylineitem_job_output.id]" target="query_output">
            <reconnect />
        </salesforce:get-query-job-results-bulk-api-v2>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="d8aa2eab-665b-448c-a385-dd8e3f00f5ba" message="#[%dw 2.0&#10;output application/json&#10;---&#10;vars.query_output]" />
    </flow>
</mule>


Did you find the root cause ? I ran into same issue. Its working fine in local machine.

see https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=001120519&type=1
